# Smarty Template Engine - Add Dynamically Extends Block

Tags: php, smarty

**[Sorry for my bad english]**

I'm trying to make my php dynamically add to my template to call the masterpage block. Below is my current show how the template code and masterpage.

**------------------- default.tpl -------------------------**

```
<!-- default.tpl -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {block name="content"}{/block}
    </div>
    {block name="javascript"}{/block}
</body>
```

**------------------- index.tpl -------------------------**

```
{extends file="default.tpl"}
{block name="content"}
    Hello World 
{/block}
```

**------------------- index.php -------------------------**

```
$this->smarty->extends('default.tpl'); //I don't know if is possible do something like this

$this->smarty->blocks('javascript',array('//cdn.jquery.com')); //I don't know if is possible do something like this too

$this->smarty->display('index');
```

Answer (score 1):

Smarty works almost the way you described but the syntax is a little bit different. This is how you need to write it:

**default.tpl** (fragment)

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    {$text}
</div>
{foreach from=$javascript item=script}
    <script src="{$script}"></script>
{/foreach}
</body>
```

**index.tpl**

```
{capture name=content}
    Hello world
{/capture}
{include file='default.tpl' text=$smarty.capture.content}
```

**index.php**

```
$this->smarty->assign('javascript', array('//cdn.jquery.com'));
$this->smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

This is how Smarty works. For more information, please read the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/). The basic usage is explained in sections 3-13.

**Update:** this solution presents the Smarty 2 way of doing things. Also, the link goes to the documentation for Smarty 2. I wasn't aware of all the new features implemented in Smarty 3. However, the way presented here works in Smarty 3 as well (I'm using Smarty 3 since 2010 but never felt the need for features that were not present in Smarty 2.)

Comment: Thanks for quickly answer... I would know too if is possible define the include file on php, not only in index.tpl

Comment: You can use `{include file=$filename}` and set the value of variable `$filename` either from PHP (`$smarty->assign('filename', 'some-template.tpl');`) or even from the template, using `assign`: `{assign var=filename value='abc.tpl'}`. Internally, `{assign}` is just a plugin that does the above-mentioned `$smarty->assign()` for you. Of course, for performance reasons it's better to do as much processing as you can from the PHP code and leave the template only run through lists, format and display the values.

Comment: Ooops, it seems my knowledge about Smarty is outdated. Smarty 3 has the functions [`{block}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.block.tpl) and [`{extends}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.extends.tpl). I just didn't read the documentation for ages. Sorry to misguide you. However, the old way (Smarty 2) I presented in this solution still works, I'm using it on my daily routine.

Answer (score 1):

Both template files look good. The problem is in the PHP file:

```
$this->smarty->extends('default.tpl'); //I don't know if is possible do something like this
```

There is no method named `extends()`. Use the template function `{extend}` in the template.

```
$this->smarty->blocks('javascript',array('//cdn.jquery.com')); //I don't know if is possible do something like this too
```

There is no method named `block()` or `blocks()`. You either define the content of the block in the child template (`index.tpl`) the same way you did with `content` or you assign the data to a template variable and display it in the template. Scalar variables can be displayed using the syntax `{$variable}` while arrays can be iterated using the `{foreach}` built-in function.

```
$this->smarty->display('index');
```

This also doesn't work because the name of the template is `'index.tpl'` and not just `'index'`. Smarty does not append the termination by itself. It just attempts to find the file using the name you provided.

I discovered all the reasons why your script does not work by adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

on top of your script. **Don't** prevent PHP display the errors on your development computer. Do this on the production server **only**.

Comment: Sorry... the $smarty->display('index') is my own function what call  inside "index.tpl"